# Looking for average economic impact of all Farmlands per acre in Florida or U.S

Tags: geospatial, usa, economics, agriculture, cost

I am researching on road alignment optimization. The research goal is to find least cost road alignment between two given points, considering highway codes. One of major factors which I want to consider, is impact of alignment on economy. To present my methodology in a case study, I need actual geospatial data on economic impact of every farm or numeric data on average economic impact of all farmlands per acre in Florida or U.S, however data for Florida would be more accurate in my case. Do you have any recommendations?